# how do you calculate number of visits for all pages in the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Assuming you have a Page model with a '''visits_count (IntegerField)''' field, how do you calculate the arithmetic mean of the number of visits for all pages in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate over the `Page`s:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

avg_visits = Page.objects.aggregate(
    avg_visits=Avg('visits_count')
)['avg_visits']
```